# Trying to save user into mySql with bcrypt. But return Error: data and salt arguments required

Tags: mysql, node.js

Trying to save user into mySql with bcrypt. But return Error: data and salt arguments required.

Here is my code

auth controller:

```
export const register = (req, res) => {
//CHECK EXISTING USER
const q = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE email = ? OR username = ?";

db.query(q, [req.body.email, req.body.username], (err, data) => {
    if (err) return res.status(500).json(err);
    if (data.length) return res.status(409).json("User already exists!");

    //Hash the password and create a user
    const salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(10);
    const hash = bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.password, salt);

    const q = "INSERT INTO users(`username`,`email`,`password`) VALUES (?)";
    const values = [req.body.username, req.body.email, hash];

    db.query(q, [values], function (err, data) {
        if (err) return res.status(500).json(err);
        return res.status(200).json("User has been created.");
    });
  });

};
```

As you can see, I already define salt, and hash by

`const salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(10);`
 `const hash = bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.password, salt);`

So I have no idea why return Error: data and salt arguments required.

Here is the error returned:

Error: data and salt arguments required
at Object.hashSync (/Users/rickyyeung/Desktop/nodejsProject/rick20230510booking/api/node_modules/bcrypt/bcrypt.js:91:15)
at Query. (file:///Users/rickyyeung/Desktop/nodejsProject/rick20230510booking/api/controllers/auth.js:14:27)
at Query. (/Users/rickyyeung/Desktop/nodejsProject/rick20230510booking/api/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:526:10)
at Query._callback (/Users/rickyyeung/Desktop/nodejsProject/rick20230510booking/api/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:488:16)
at Query.Sequence.end (/Users/rickyyeung/Desktop/nodejsProject/rick20230510booking/api/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:83:24)
at Query._handleFinalResultPacket (/Users/rickyyeung/Desktop/nodejsProject/rick20230510booking/api/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Query.js:149:8)
at Query.EofPacket (/Users/rickyyeung/Desktop/nodejsProject/rick20230510booking/api/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Query.js:133:8)
at Protocol._parsePacket (/Users/rickyyeung/Desktop/nodejsProject/rick20230510booking/api/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:291:23)
at Parser._parsePacket (/Users/rickyyeung/Desktop/nodejsProject/rick20230510booking/api/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:433:10)
at Parser.write (/Users/rickyyeung/Desktop/nodejsProject/rick20230510booking/api/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:43:10)
rickyyeung@Rickys-MacBook-Air api %

Comment: 3 `?` on `VALUES` instead of 1 - [ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70238296/trying-to-pass-variables-into-a-prepared-statement-in-javascript-node-js)?

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems here,

one : You passed only one value to the sql, but needed to pass 3 values :

```js
const q = "INSERT INTO users(`username`,`email`,`password`) VALUES (?)";
const values = [req.body.username, req.body.email, hash];
```

When inserting value into the DB, in this case you provided only one value  `VALUES (?)";`, when it should be like  `VALUES (?,?,?)";` to match arguments you passed in the `const values` : `req.body.username, req.body.email, hash`

as for the hash issue :

It seems like the `req.body.password` is empty. make sure the check for null or undefined.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but why would it be empty, I actually input password in postman.

Comment: I tried VALUES (?,?,?). it is not working. seems it is not the related issue.

Comment: did you check req.body.password is not empty ?

Comment: Sorry, how to check? use console.log(req.body.password)?

Comment: Sorry, I am new to coding

Comment: @Rickyforcode It's ok, yes. ```console.log(req.body.password)``` , verify that this parameter is not empty.